# Screenshots & pdfs severly scaled down in OneNote

Tags: macbook-pro, onenote

Whenever I take a screenshot (copied to clipboard) in my Macbook Air M1 and paste it into OneNote its dimensions seem to be much less than the original.

Here is an example: (both screenshots below were taken using cmd-shift-s, the edited keybinding for capturing pictures copied to clipboard)

**Original:**

[image]

**Pasted into OneNote:**
[image]

The same goes for any pdf I print into OneNote- the image of each page is scaled down; how can I fix this?

Comment: OneNote scales pasted images to fit the current box. If you right-click on the pasted image and select "Restore image to original size" that usually works for me

Comment: @SteveChambers That wasn't the case with Windows' OneNote. Anyway, is it possible to change this default behaviour since I take many screenshots and hence doing this for every pic would be tedious?

Comment: Funny, I've been using OneNote on Windows for years and it has always done that. But I am not aware of any settings you can make to change the default behavior. There are a lot of Add Ins for OneNote on Windows that customize OneNote extensively, but they don't usually work on the Mac version, too bad.

Answer (score 0):

@Steve Chambers +1 has the correct answer: the context menu on the picture itself allows you to "Restore Image to Original Size", but I thought I would add some additional info.

I ran into this using the Teams app on Mac, since MS recently (2023) migrated the Teams Wiki capability to OneNote.  There IS NO context menu in the Teams OneNote capability (at least in the Mac Teams app). In fact when you enlarge the image, it gets to a point where it won't expand in the vertical direction, only horizontally.  The context menu allows only Grow, Shrink and Crop, which just zooms the low-res version of the image.

I opened the same Note up in my OneNote app on Mac, and then the context menu was available. OneNote appears to store the full-res image, because I was able to paste into Teams, and then perform the "restore" using the OneNote app. It appeared fine in the OneNote app; however, when I went back to Teams, the image was larger, but it was an upsampled low-res image, rather than the full-res version.  Conversely, when I pasted the image in using the OneNote app and then Restored to original size, the image in Teams WAS higher resolution.  So, I recommend you do your pasting and resizing in the OneNote app, and not within the Teams Note tabs.

I also noted that the OneNote app has a "Rotate" option in the context menu that is not in the Teams app, allowing you to correct for Right, Left, and Flips.

BTW, for those interested in getting a "Default" capability, I tried pasting in other pictures in the Mac OneNote app, and (at least in this one session), the pictures all pasted in at full-res and I didn't have to use the "Restore" menu item.